# duplicate records with different values in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a people table with a column of industries and name. I can get the values based on industries by using the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `people`
ORDER BY `industry` ASC, `name` ASC
```

in my tables there are records(people) with same industries. Is there a possibility to have them under same output?
for now the query returns this

```
industry1 
------ 
name1

industry1 
------ 
name2   

industry2 
------ 
name 
----------------------------------------------------
```

how can I have it in this way?

```
industry1 
------  
name1
name2  

industry2 
------ 
name
```

```html
  var num = 0;
  for(var i = 0;i < r.length; i++) {
  var country = r[i].country;  
    if(i < r.length-1) nextCountry = r[i+1].country;
    
    
    
    if(lastCountry != country && nextCountry == country) {
      num = 0;
    }
  %>
  
    <div class="<%= lastCountry %> <%= country %> <%= nextCountry %>"></div>
      <div class="contact-list">
        <div class="contact-info contact-padding">
          <% if(r[i].industry) { %> <h2 class="h-style"><%= r[i].industry %></h2> <% }%> 
          <span class="name"><%= r[i].name %> <% if(r[i].segment) { %>&#40;<%= r[i].segment %>&#41;<% }%></span>
          <span class="phone"><%= r[i].phone %></span>
          <span class="email"><%@ "generic_email" %></span>
        </div>
      </div>
   
    <% 
   num++;
    var lastCountry = country;
   }

  %>
```

this is view that I built and consume the data, it simply repeats same pieces of code for each record. If I try to use GROUP BY, it only returns

```
ONE OF THE INDUSTRIES

name1, name2,name3,name4, ...
phone number
email
```

Comment: Means you want to show result in one column ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum yes, people with same industry tags should be grouped in one column

Comment: Seriously, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement clearly, you need something like

```
SELECT `industry`,GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as name
FROM `people`
GROUP BY `industry`
ORDER BY `industry` ASC
```

This will give you `1` row per `industry` and `name` concatenated by `comma`. If you want different `separator` like pipe or space, use `GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR <custom separator>)`

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT, concat  all the names in one row under a column of industry. It eliminates all other industries and only keep the last one. As result, I just have one industry with all the names under it. didn't help

Comment: `It eliminates all other industries and only keep the last one` => there is nothing called `last` or `first` when you are using `group by`. You will get rows for all `distinct` industries, ie `industry1` `industry2`. Add the sample data and expected output in tabular format in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use GROUP BY for these two columns.

SELECT *
FROM people
GROUP BY industry,name
ORDER BY `industry` ASC, `name` ASC